# Use Windows findstr to list files not containing a string

Tags: cmd, findstr

From Windows CMD I can use

```
findstr -m subroutine *.f90
```

to list all files with suffix .f90 containing "subroutine". To list all .f90 files not containing the string I can do something like

```
dir /b *.f90 > files.txt
findstr -m subroutine *.f90 > files_with_string.txt
```

and then write a script to list the lines in files.txt not found in files_with_string.txt. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `/v` option in `findstr`, but that wouldn't help here.
Process each file with a `for` loop, try to find the string and if it doesn't find it (`||`), echo the filename:

```
for %a in (*.f90) do @findstr "subroutine" "%a" >nul || echo %a
```

(above is command line syntax. For use in a batchfile, use `%%a` instead of `%a` (all three occurences))

Answer (score 1):

I needed to search for filenames which contained one specific string ("up"), but did not contain another string ("packages").

However, I was hoping to run it from the command line.

This is actually possible to do, you just have to call `findstr` twice.

Mine looked like:
`dir /B /S up | findstr /I "up" | findstr /I /v "packages"`

That means:

1. search all directories (/S & subdirs)
2. give me the bare formatting (/B)
3. and pass it through (| pipe) findstr (/I ignore case) to find ones that have "up" then
4. pass the results (| pipe) through findstr again but this time ignore all that
   contain (/v) "packages"

If you have items like:

- c:\test\packages\up
- c:\extra\thing\up
- c:\extra\thing\packages\up
- c:\extra\test\up
- c:\extra\test\nothing

The results would be only the ones that contain "up" but do not contain "packages"

- c:\extra\thing\up
- c:\extra\test\up

#### Call findstr /v multiple times on result

In other words you can keep passing the result into another findstr with /v to remove the ones that have additional words you don't want.